# is "lift" using an eta expansion in "Functional Programming in Scala"?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In section 4.3.2 of **Functional Programming in Scala** there's a definition of a function that I don't quite understand. I can see that it works, but I'm not sure why.

```
   def lift[A,B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = _ map f
```

In the above statement is the '_' an eta expansion? I can tell you that the ScalaIDE (eclipse plugin) tells me it's an Option[A]. So of course you can rewrite the above as:

```
   def lift2[A,B](f: A => B): Option[A] => Option[B] = { oa: Option[A] => oa map f }
```

But what I'm wondering is how the compiler knows that the **_** is going to be an Option[A] in the first definition. Is it really as simple as "because the return type says we're defining a function that takes an Option[A] as it's argument"?

Comment: Yes, it really is that simple. Scala type inference in general is complex and undocumented, but that's all it's doing in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> In the above statement is the '_' an eta expansion?

The _ in this context is a shorthand for a lambda expression, and is exactly equivalent to 
`(oa => oa map f)`

> because the return type says we're defining a function that takes an Option[A] as it's argument

Yes. What you may be missing here is that functions are values in Scala. The return type of  `lift` is `Option[A] => Option[B]`, therefore in the expression `(oa => oa map f)`, oa must be of type `Option[A]`.